# Click event on textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events

I want to add a click event to a textbox but my code isn't working. When the textbox is clicked the event doesn't run.

Here is the code behind

```
public class Day : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public delegate void ClickEventHandler(object sender, ClickEventArgs e);

    public event Application_IAD.TEST.Day.ClickEventHandler onClick;

    protected virtual void onTheClick()
    {
        if (onClick != null) onClick(this, new ClickEventArgs(new Day()));
    }
} 

public class Cal : Control
{
    public ObservableCollection<Day> Days { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler<ClickEventArgs> DayClick;

    public Cal()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        CurrentDate = DateTime.Today;
        DayNames = new ObservableCollection<string> {"Dim", "Lun", "Mar", "Mer", "Jeu", "Ven", "Sam"};

        Days = new ObservableCollection<Day>();
        BuildCalendar(DateTime.Today);
    }

    public void BuildCalendar(DateTime targetDate)
    {
        Days.Clear();

        //Show 6 weeks each with 7 days = 42
        for (int box = 1; box <= 42; box++)
        {
            Day day = new Day {Date = d, Enabled = true, IsTargetMonth = targetDate.Month == d.Month};
            day.onClick += test;
        }
    }

    private void test(object sender, ClickEventArgs e)
    {
        DayClick(this, new ClickEventArgs(sender as Day));
    }
}
```

Here is the XAML

```
 <Calen:Cal x:Name="Calendar" Margin="0,50,0,0" DayChanged="Calendar_DayChanged" DayClick="Calendar_DayClick"/>
```

I don't know where the error is or know what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement WPF TextBox control (e.g. TextBox1) event subscription in two different ways as shown below in following sample code snippets:

Using C# Lambda-expression (shortest code syntax):

```
TextBox1.PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) => { //YOUR CODE};
```

More traditional way (longer syntax):

```
TextBox1.PreviewMouseDown += (s, e) => TextBox_PreviewMouseDown(s, e);
private void TextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
           TextBox _tb = sender as TextBox;
          // THE REST OF YOUR CODE
        }
        catch { }
}
```

Also useful event subscription sample pertinent to WPF TextBox:

```
TextBox1.TextChanged += (s, e) => { // YOUR CODE };
```

Hope this may help. Kind regards,